# How can I insert a new row in a different section when I delete that row for TableViews?

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
var deletedItems = String()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            deletedItems = documents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else {
            recentlyDeleted.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        recentlyDeleted.insert(deletedItems, at: recentlyDeleted.count)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

I want to have it where if I delete a row from section 0, I want it to reappear in a recently deleted list in section 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if indexPath.section == 0 { 
 let deletedItem = documents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
 recentlyDeleted.append(deletedItem)
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:recentlyDeleted.count -1 ,section:1)], with: .fade) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to append document for certain index to `recentlyDeleted` array. Then you want to remove this document from `documents` array. After that just delete row for removed document and insert row for new recently deleted document.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    recentlyDeleted.append(documents[indexPath.row])
    documents.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: recentlyDeleted.endIndex, section: 1)], with: .fade)
}
```